# How do I enable Dota 2's ability suggestions in-game?

Tags: dota-2

I am new to Dota 2 and I heard there was ability suggestions in the game that showed a percentage of the pick rate per level.

How do I enable that so I see the percent above my skills in-game? Here a picture of what I mean.[image: Ability Suggestions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the screenshot, this is a feature of the Plus Assistant, which is part of the [Dota Plus](https://www.dota2.com/plus) subscription.

The Plus Assistant is automatically activated while subscribed to Dota Plus, but can be disabled from Advanced Options in the settings.